# show jquery spinner when checkbox is clicked

Tags: jquery, spinner

I am having a table which is having around 500 rows with fields for every day of the current month.
The columns of table are as follows.

> Vendor | 1 | 2 | ...... | 31

Now depending on the day the `<TD>` has class as Mo for Monday , Tu for Tuesday etc.

I also have a table with 7 checkboxes one for each day
i.e. [ ] Monday [ ] Tuesday ..... [ ] Sunday
Code for it is as follows

```
<table><tr>  
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="Mo" name="Mo" checked onclick="ToggleDay('Mo')">Mo</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="Tu" name="Tu" checked onclick="ToggleDay('Tu')">Tu</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="We" name="We" checked onclick="ToggleDay('We')">We</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="Th" name="Th" checked onclick="ToggleDay('Th')">Th</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="Fr" name="Fr" checked onclick="ToggleDay('Fr')">Fr</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="Sa" name="Sa" checked onclick="ToggleDay('Sa')">Sa</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="Su" name="Su" checked onclick="ToggleDay('Su')">Su</td>
</tr></table>
```

Code for the function is as follows

```
function ToggleDay(daynm) {
  loading.open();  
  var myvar1 = "#" + daynm;
  if ($(myvar1).is(":checked"))
    $('.' + daynm).show("slow");
  else
    $('.' + daynm).hide("slow");
  loading.close();
}
```

The above code should work like when I un-check any day  eg. Monday then it should first remove checked mark from check box, show spinner, hide all TD where class is "Mo" and finally hide spinner.

It works, it takes 5 to 6 second to do full operation. But when I un-check the check box it updates the pages all after completing the operation. i.e. the user will still see the check mark even when he has clicked the check-box.

Is there any way to flush the action inbetween show that the page gets refreshed after every logical action is complete. i.e. User should see uncheck the box immediately then see the spinner and after 5 to 6 second when all  with the class day "Mo" is hidden should hide the spinner.

Comment: 5, 6 seconds to handle 500 rows? This should be done in max 200ms.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. Is your problem that the browser doesn't uncheck de checkbox until the processing is done?

Comment: Yes the browser uncheks or de checks the checkbox only after it completes all operations

Answer (score 0):

Try make the process async:

```
function ToggleDay(daynm) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        loading.open();  
        var myvar1 = "#" + daynm;
        if ($(myvar1).is(":checked"))
            $('.' + daynm).show("slow");
        else
            $('.' + daynm).hide("slow");
        loading.close();
    }, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works for checking and un-checking the checkbox. i.e. It shows immediate result. But it does not show the spinner. Anyways thanks.

Comment: Maybe try moving the `loading.open();` outside (before) the `setTimeout`

Comment: I did that but of no use.